# Import a function from a different module

Tags: c++, llvm

Say a function `f_a` in module `m_a` calls another function `f_b` in module `m_b`. This is the only reference across module `m_a`. Now, I'd like to make module `m_a` self-contained, i.e. eliminate references to the other module. However, module `m_b` is very large in size. (In this case it contains all maths functions in fast/accurate and single/double implementation). Is there a way to only add function `f_b` to module `m_a` using LLVM C++ API? Or do I have to use the linker API and merge the whole module `m_b` into `m_a`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a text editor and cut'n'paste the function to the target module. If you link the whole m_b, the linker should still be able to detect that large parts of it aren't used and discard them when creating the final executable. What exactly is the issue you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

In general you need the linker, the function in module b could use variables only declared there and other functions there, you should inspect the code to be able to do that for a generic function. The linker would be the solution that would work in every case.